# Custom patterns for stream analytics blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

My question is about saving out data from stream analytics to blob storage . In our system we are collecting clictstream-data from many websites via event hubs. Then we are doing some small grouping and aggregating. After that we send the results to our blob storage.

The problem is we want to seperate our results to many blob containers by id for each website. Now we can only do it by date and time pattern like /logs/{date}/{time} but we want /{websiteID}/{date}/{time}

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream Analytics: Dynamic output path based on message payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233928/stream-analytics-dynamic-output-path-based-on-message-payload)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question:

[Stream Analytics: Dynamic output path based on message payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233928/stream-analytics-dynamic-output-path-based-on-message-payload)

[Azure Stream Analytics -> how much control over path prefix do I really have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557440/azure-stream-analytics-how-much-control-over-path-prefix-do-i-really-have)

The short version of the above is you can't do this in Stream Analytics. If you have too many target paths for multiple sinks to be feasible, your best bet is to stream to a single blob store sink and process the results with something other than ASA. Azure Functions, WebJobs or ADF tasks are a few possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is we want to seperate our results to many blob containers by id for each website. Now we can only do it by date and time pattern like /logs/{date}/{time} but we want /{websiteID}/{date}/{time}

As this official document [stream-analytics-define-outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs) mentioned about `Path Prefix Pattern` of Blob storage output:

> The file path used to write your blobs within the specified container.
>   Within the path, you may choose to use one or more instances of the following 2 variables to specify the frequency that blobs are written:
>   **{date}**, **{time}**
>
> Example 1: cluster1/logs/{date}/{time}
>
> Example 2: cluster1/logs/{date}

Based on my understanding, you could create multiple blob output targets from a single Stream Analytics job for each of your websites, and in your SQL-like query language, you could filter the event data and send data to the specific output. For more details, you could refer to [Common query patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns#query-example-send-data-to-multiple-outputs).

Comment: how can i do this dynamically? I dont want to do that for each of them like: select * into Output1 from Input where id=1;select * into Output2 from Input where id=2

Comment: As I known, you could not do this dynamically via Azure Stream Analytics. Creating multiple blob output targets or multiple jobs for each of your websites is a simpler way for you to achieve your purpose. Or you could follow Pete M's suggestions, but at this point, you need to do a lot work by yourself.